# Parsing Ruby on Rails Parameters (with a # instead of a ?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, parameters

I have an application that I am building and the user eveuntually gets redirected to a url on my application like this www.myapp.com/path/#access_token=lkjh8usoij93. How can I parse the access token using ruby on rails? It does not show up as a supplied parameter.

Comment: You might want to include the related code so that people can better help you. That is an oddly formatted URL and there might be a better solution than trying to parse it in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get anchors with Rails (on server side). You can get it only with javascript `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to get access_token.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    access_token = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
}
```